# QSerialPort ->write() or read() not as expected on clicked() signal

Tags: qt, arduino

I'm working on a Qt5 project. I have a button that issues a clicked() signal and its slot has the following code which writes to the serial port:

```
void Dialog::on_startStream_clicked()
{
    QByteArray ba;
    if(esp->isOpen()){
        esp->write("1");
        if(esp->canReadLine()){
            ba = esp->readLine();
            ba.replace("\xFE", "");
            ba = ba.simplified();
            QString ba_with_time = stamp->currentDateTime().toString("MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss  ");
            ba_with_time.append(ba);
            ui->output->appendPlainText(ba_with_time);
            qDebug() << ba_with_time;
        }
    }
}
```

After establishing the connection to the serial port, the first time I click on the button nothing happens. Subsequent clicks work correctly.

I'm using PlatformIO to upload the Arduino code to the ESP32 and in the PlatformIO serial monitor there is output immediately after I issue the command on the first time, which makes me think the problem is my Qt code.

How can I fix it so that Qt can read the buffer on the first button click?

Comment: If you use of serialPort readyRead signal, it will work every time. In your code it seems like a wrong timing in the first button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QByteArry ba; // member of Dialog class

// connect the QSerialPort::readyRead() signal after creation of esp

connect(esp, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &Dialog::onDataReady);

...

void Dialog::on_startStream_clicked()
{
    if(esp->isOpen()){
        esp->write("1");
    }
}

// The "onDataReady()" is called every time you receive data via serial port

void Dialog::onDataReady()
{
    do{
        ba += esp->readAll(); // buffer received data
        int i = ba.indexOf("\n"); // i assume your message is \n terminated
        if(i != -1){ 
            QByteArray ba1 = ba.mid(0, i);
            // modify the data
            qDebug() << ba1;
            ba.remove(0, i); // remove message from receive buffer
        }
    } while(esp->bytesAvailable());
}
```

Comment: You may add a timeout, just in case you do not receive the '\n' within a certain amount of time.